# python function return first non zero strip middle zeros and return last part of number string

Tags: python

Given a number texted string like '0104002' I need a return `01` `4002`.

Basically return the first part of the number text string when the the number is greater than 0. Then for the second part return the portion that starts with the next nonzero number until the end of the string. number placements will vary for each input, string will not be the same length

I have only been able to get the first part of what I need so far

```
def lot(num):
    lot=""
    for x in num:
        lot+=x
        y=int(x)
        if y>0: break
    print lot

lot('0104002')
```

Comment: Is the first part always going to be a 2-digit num?

Comment: no its always going to change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like something which is trivial for a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^(0*[^0]+)0+([^0].*)$', '0104002').groups()
('01', '4002')
```

This regex defines two groups which are split by one or more zeroes. The split is defined by the first series of zeroes to appear after the first series of non-zeroes. What comes before that split falls into the first group, and what comes after that falls into the second group.

For anyone who finds regex intimidating, here's the "verbose" explanatory version.

```
re.match(
    r'''^
        (        # Begin first group
          0*     # Allow for some number of leading zeroes
          [^0]+  # Match a series of non-zeroes
        )        # End first group
        0+       # Match some series of zeroes (the separator)
        (        # Begin second group
          [^0]   # Match the first non-zero character
          .*     # Match anything afterward
        )        # End second group
        $
    ''',
    '0104002',
    flags=re.VERBOSE).groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

While regex is probably the best way to do this, if you aren't allowed to for whatever reason you can index your string and slice it as soon as you find the number.

```
def lot(num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        if(num[i] != "0"): #if you encounter a character that isn't 0
            print(num[:i+1], int(num[i+1:]))    
            return num[:i+1], str(int(num[i+1:])) #return the two halves

lot('0104002')
```

I included both a print and return, because you asked to return them but you in your code only printed it them.

Comment: ahh I like the thinking but the second number returned in your function keeps the leading zero

Comment: i used this instead to strip the leading zero

Comment: print(num[:i+1], str(int(num[i+1:])))

Comment: @ziggy for the print statement, `str` is redundant, because if it is an `int` the `print` function calls `repr` which has similar behavior to `str`

Comment: This won't work as expected for any number where the first group has more than one non-zero character. Example: `lot('01204002')` would give `('01', '204002')`, where I think the expected output is `('012', '4002')`.

Comment: I gave it the same behavior as the function OP said worked for getting the first part. I'll fix it if it's supposed to do what yours does.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lot(num):
   lot=""
   parts = []
   for x in num:
      lot+=x
      y=int(x)
      if y>0:
         print lot, num[len(lot):]
         parts.append(lot)
         parts.append(num[len(lot):])
         break
   print parts

lot('0104002')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful for you:

```
def lot(num):
    lot=""
    z=0
    for x in num:
        lot+=x
        y=int(x)
        if y>0:
            z=num.index(x)
            break
    print (lot)
    print (num[z+1:].strip("0"))

lot('0104002')
```